# Limiting the number of top level menu items in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, menu, hook, drupal-8

Is there a way to limit the number of top level menu items in Drupal 8? I suppose this could be done using hooks. I am very new to the Drupal eco system and not sure where to begin.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, if you simply want to turn off some menu items which are there currently, you can typically do this through the admin UI. When you're logged into the Drupal backend, go to Structure and then Menus in the toolbar. Find the menu you want to change in the list of menus (might just be called main menu) and click the edit menu button next to it.

You should see a list of all the items in that menu - you can either delete them, which will remove them from the menu structure all together, or you can disable them (uncheck the 'enabled' checkbox, don't forget to save after you've done this) - disabling them leaves them in the menu structure but they are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can limit the number of top level menu in your block layout configure menu and there is a tab the "menu level" /admin/structure/block/manage/bartik_main_menu

Comment: I want to restrict on the CMS end not the front/theme end